# Trying to send this form POST request using cURL

Tags: curl, post

```
<form method="POST" action="https://testnet.demo.example.org/api/v1/invoices" class="btcpay-form btcpay-form--block" id='btc'>
  <input type="hidden" name="storeId" value="FG7Zz9dtP7DYvEUDq73K59EKvjMWox7nvnUhfCGMKsux" />
   <input type="hidden" name="price" value="10" />
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="USD" />
  <input type="image" class="submit" name="submit" src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/3/Submit-Button-PNG-Clipart.png" style="width:209px" alt="">
 </form>
```

How can I send this request using curl ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly is the problem here:

- Did you try reading [curl's documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) ?
- Did you find how to emulate forms ?
  Try `-F` or `--form` in curl. All the examples are on the [curl's manual page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), including the image.
- Do you understand your HTML code and what it will represent as POST ? (try reading some form tutorial if not)